# Ubuntu 14.04 theme (?) changed after restart

Tags: 14.04, themes

I restarted my PC and after the restart the theme (?) had changed. Windows (like Firefox and Chromium) and menus (like the right-click menu) were different like that:

[image: browserclose]

I don't know why it happened or how to change it back.

Comment: Try running `apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop unity`.

Comment: Also try `sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool`. Search for `Tweak Tool` in Unity Dash, open it, go into `Icons` and select `Restore Defaults`.

Comment: Any updates applied before the reboot?

Comment: @ElderGeek no updated were applied immediately after the reboot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two powerful tools you can use to change and fine tune the themes of your ubuntu desktop:

1.Unity tweak tool.

To install:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool
```

To run:

```
unity-tweak-tool
```

2.Gnome Tweak Tool

To install, run the following commands in an open terminal (ctrl alt t):

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool
```

To run:

```
gnome-tweak-tool
```

Specifically, you need to adjust your gtk theme.

It looks like you have some qt theme going on there. Allot of times, all you have to do is use gnome-tweak-tool or the unity counterpart to toggle from a couple of themes and back to the default one to get it to return to normal.

Comment: using the gnome tweak tool should give ownership of your default theme back to gtk from qt as gnome is gtk, kde is qt, and unity (compiz) is actually ambiguous even though gtk is installed by default.

Comment: Disclaimer for future readers: I have not used this solution as I re-installed Ubuntu but I accept this answer as it seems the most promising.

Answer (score 2):

The default theme for Ubuntu is Ambiance. You can set it by searching for Appearance in the Launcher, run it and change the theme as shown here:

[image: appearance]

Comment: The theme remains Ambience. I checked it. It never changed. :/

Comment: Is this what you are used to seeing? http://imgur.com/pLlTeov

Comment: Yes exactly that.

Comment: @Adam try changing it to something else and then back again to see if that works, otherwise, you'll have to use one of the tweak tools to do the job.

Comment: @mchid I tried all the available options regarding the theme and it was not changing. Also I tried to re-install Unity as it is mentioned in one comment but nothing again.

Comment: @Adam hmmmm, you didn't say anything about using gnome-tweak tool. Any reason for that?

Comment: @mchid I didn't used that. I don't even know what this is. :P

Comment: @Adam read my answer

Comment: @mchid I didn't see that you had posted an answer. I will thank you.